# Why regular expression is not working in NodeJs

Tags: regex, node.js, express

I've blocked `'api', 'components', 'app', 'bower_components', 'assets'` in my website as follow:

```
app.route('/:url(api|components|app|bower_components|assets)/*')
    .get(errors[404]);
```

Unfortunately, I can be able to access when I type 'http://localhost/api' in my website. Please let me know which one is missing or wrong in above code. Thanks.

Comment: What does `:url` do?

Comment: Provided the syntax is correct you might also try to add a slash, eg `'/:url\/(api|components|app|bower_components|assets)/*'` (note that the backslash might need doubling).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression: /^\/(?:([^/]+?))\/(?(?:([^/]+?))|components|app|bower_components|assets)\/(.*)\/?$/: Invalid group

Comment: Sure it is invalid, you have `(?(` syntax that is not supported. Replace with `(?:(`. However, I cannot help more now since I'm on a mobile.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I don't have (?( that syntax in my code.

Comment: You do : `...([^/]+?))\/(?(?:...`

Comment: @Thomas nope, I did only. '/:url\/(api|components|app|bower_components|assets)/*'

Comment: And. What about [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36002628/why-regular-expression-is-not-working-in-nodejs#comment59660334_36002628)?

Comment: @Thomas that is error message shown by Node when I change that one, '/:url\/(api|components|app|bower_components|assets)/*'

Answer (score -1):

Your example is working, try to access your app with http://localhost:3000/api 
I made one functional example:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();


app.route('/:url(api|components|app|bower_components|assets)/*')
  .get(function blockRoutes(req, res, next){
    console.log('req.params.url: ',req.params.url);
    res.status(404).send('not found');
  });

app.get('/api', function (req, res) {
  res.send('API accessed!');
});

app.listen(3000, function () {
  console.log('Example app listening on port 3000!');
});
```

test this example with
http://localhost:3000/api  // how returns 200
http://localhost:3000/api/something  // how returns 404

Comment: Example created with: express@4.13.4